# Uncountable Discrete set

Tags: real-analysis

I’m reading that in $\Bbb R$ with the standard topology, discrete sets are countable. Due to the denseness of the rationals in $\Bbb R$, each point exists in an open set with rational endpoints, and the union of these open sets is countable. My confusion comes from the fact that the irrationals are also dense in $\Bbb R$. Couldn’t we say the points in the discrete set exist in an open set with irrational end points, — and claim the same set is uncountable?

I apologize if this is poorly worded. I’m trying to self study and don’t have the language down yet.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Use `$\Bbb R$` for the output $\Bbb R$. 

Answer (score 3):

You are forgetting something. The logic that says that each point is contained in an open interval with rational endpoints, shows that the set of points is **at most** countable, because of the one-one map of the set of points to the set of intervals with rational endpoints. But this set could also be finite e.g. consist of just one point.

In the same fashion, doing the logic with irrationals would just tell you that the set is **at most** uncountable, which is not useful information(in the light of the previous argument) but rather trivially true once you know that $\mathbb R$ is uncountable. Of course, any atmost countable set is atmost uncountable, so the former argument uses the fact that the rationals are exactly a countable set.